# npm cordova install on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, cordova, windows-phone-8, windows-10

I am unable to install Cordova on Windows 10 using the command `npm install -g cordova` as the following error is obtained in `npm-debug.log`:

```
24743 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\abbrev-7bb988b9' -> 'C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npm\node_modules\abbrev'
24743 verbose stack     at destStatted (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\action\finalize.js:25:7)
24743 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:264:29
24743 verbose stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
24743 verbose stack
24743 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\abbrev-7bb988b9' -> 'C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npm\node_modules\abbrev'
24743 verbose stack     at Error (native)
24744 verbose cwd C:\WINDOWS\system32
24745 error Windows_NT 10.0.15063
24746 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova"
24747 error node v6.11.2
24748 error npm  v3.10.10
24749 error path C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\abbrev-7bb988b9
24750 error code ENOENT
24751 error errno -4058
24752 error syscall rename
24753 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\abbrev-7bb988b9' -> 'C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npm\node_modules\abbrev'
24754 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\abbrev-7bb988b9' -> 'C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npm\node_modules\abbrev'
24754 error enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
24754 error enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
```

Comment: did you try `npm cache clean` and then install command?

Comment: @suraj didn't help, still getting the same error.

Comment: Follow this link https://evothings.com/doc/build/cordova-install-windows.html
Make sure you have installed latest version of node js

Comment: I have the latest LTS of node.js but still the command `npm install -g cordova` isn't completing successfully.

Comment: try deleting everything in .staging folder..

Comment: check your error `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging`

Comment: The folder `.staging` does not exist at that location, even if I enable the view hidden files option.